# Defining @property.setter in Abstract Base Class gives AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, abc

An Abstract Base Class `Base` has a `@abstractmethod` named `data` which is also a `@property`.

**Question:** Is there a way to define the property setter `data.setter` in the `Base` class, so that we don't have to repeatedly define the setter method in all the subclasses (i.e. `Foo`)?

**Code showing AttributeError when defining `data.setter` in ABC**

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

def reload_data():
    return ['hello']


class Base(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def data(self):
        pass

    @data.setter               # <----- AttributeError if this is defined here
    def data(self, value):
        self._data = value


class Foo(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = None

    @property
    def data(self):
        if self._data is None:
            self._data = reload_data()
        return self._data

    # @data.setter              # <----- Defining it here avoids AttributeError, but 
    # def data(self, value):             causes code repetition in all the subclasses of Base
    #     self._data = value

foo = Foo()
foo.data = ['world']
print(foo.data)
```

Comment: Did you try the example in https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, I tried reading the linked doc but lack the knowledge to understand how to apply it to my issue. Any help here will be highly appreciated!

Comment: There isn't too much knowledge needed; it shows a setter being applied, you just need to change the name.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Following the recipe in the docs does not solve the problem.

Comment: Then please give a [mcve] of that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way to do it with `@property` decorators, but doing it "manually" as shown below seems to work.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


def reload_data():
    return ['hello']


class Base(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def _get_data(self):
        pass

    # Non-abstract.
    def _set_data(self, value):
        self._data = value


class Foo(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = None

    # Define inherited abstract method.
    def _get_data(self):
        if self._data is None:
            self._data = reload_data()
        return self._data

    data = property(_get_data, Base._set_data)


foo = Foo()
foo.data = ['world']
print(foo.data)  # ['world']
```